# Make a button that displays in all fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make a button that lies at the bottom and will show on all the fragments. This is my xml layout for the activity that contains the fragment. Fragments are scrollable and the bottom button is always displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_store_info"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sendbest.ibooking.ibooking_customer.StoreInfo">

<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:stl_indicatorAlwaysInCenter="false"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInFront="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="bottom"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#ff4081"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="4dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth="auto"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:stl_overlineColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_overlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_underlineColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="1dp"
    app:stl_dividerColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="1dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="true"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="12sp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="16dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="0dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="false"
    app:stl_clickable="true"
    app:stl_titleOffset="24dp"
    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="false"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewpagertab"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewpager"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="bottom button"
    android:background="#e50013"
    android:id="@+id/btShopping"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The tab and viewpager works fine now, however the button cannot be displayed. What is the correct way to apply this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your `ViewPager` (XML):

```
android:layout_above="@+id/btShopping"
```

and remove this from the same Button:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
```

The issue with your code is that the ViewPager is covering the whole Activity and even if the `Button` is set to be just below it, it gets out of activity screen.

Comment: Thank you, I did tried putting the layout_above but didn't remove the layout_below. This solved it i will accept your answer once time is up

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line `android:layout_below="@id/viewpager"` from your button. It will display in all fragment.

Answer (score 1):

remove this from button

```
android:layout_below="@id/viewpager"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change parent layout which in your case in `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Then in `ViewPager` change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` and add another line of `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Hope in this way, you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

because you set the viewpager mathc_parent and set button below viewpager, the button out of the screen.